# How to deploy WAR file to Azure App Services created using Docker OPEN Liberty Image

Tags: azure, websphere-liberty, docker-image

Hello I have pulled a Docker Image (OPEN Liberty) and I have created an Azure Web-app using this docker image. The webapp renders good as its clean slate.
I would like to know how I can deploy a WAR file to this app service (which uses OPEN Liberty) I tried the bash and war deploy as mentioned in microsoft docs but that doesnt help. Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This readme](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.tutorials/tree/master/app) shows a few ways to add a war to an image. You will likely need to create an application image on top of OpenLiberty and deploy that image to Azure, which is covered in the "Create an application layer" section.

To summarize the steps:

1. Create a docker file that adds your war to `/config/dropins`.
2. Optionally add a `server.xml` file to configure your server.
3. Build this image, and publish it to a container registry like Dockerhub. Azure may provide a private registry for your use.
4. Specify that image to deploy to Azure instead of the OpenLiberty image directly.

Comment: ty Iwestby, this helps.